# Form submission for mvc model enumerable using editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an editor template for my model view ViewSetup. My view to use template is simplified as

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewSetup>
@Html.EditorFor(s => s)
```

My ViewSetup editor template has form submission like below:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{   
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.TradingPartner.ID)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

So basically i need a form to be submitted for each element of the Enumerable. But I'm facing a problem on form submission. My controller to process post is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ViewSetup formDataSent)
{
    formDataSent.Save();    
}
```

As per default model binding I'm getting null for TradingPartner property since the name in the html is :

```
<input name="[0].TradingPartner.ID" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

What I need is to submit only the ViewSetup object on each element instead of an array. If I can get the index part in the name removed that could work for me. But I'm not sure how to get just the ViewSetup object on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that if you base your editor on one item instead of a list of items then you would gain more flexibility.

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewSetup>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.TradingPartner)
}
```

Comment: No but I have many properties for ViewSetup model. its more complex than this but I have just simplified with a single property above.

Comment: Perhaps look at using partials. Each partial can have a model and call upon other partials with child model. However, this will add more verbosity.

Comment: I have to use templates since i have to reuse this in many places in my app. 

Is there some way i can submit each element in form loop (only way i see is without the index getting added to html name)..thanks.

Comment: Well if your editor for TradingPartner submits to a controller that takes a trading partner you should be good and that would take care of the index being added. However, you need to create a controller method that takes a TradingPartner from a post. I don't know about other things going on with your view.

Comment: Well, I have to submit each ViewSetup model from an enumerable. Each ViewSetup is to be submitted in an html form.
problem is TradingPartner is not getting mapped due to the [0] in html name. Its null. I dont want the index in my name somehow. 
I dont need an editor for properties in the ViewSetup model.

Comment: Just to add the TradingPartner is a public property and also the ID. I have defined the default parameterless constructor for TradingPartner property class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what resolved it for me was this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.TradingPartner, null, "")
}
```

The third property of the EditorFor being blank will get rid of the "[0]" from your objects.